# Functional difference: state variable vs instance variable with setState({})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question has been asked multiple times and discussed elsewhere on internet as well. However I could not find any reason as to why state would be better for some data than instance variable, except to maintain some separation.

One could substitute -

```
   this.setState({variableA: "xyz"});  // access variable as this.state.variableA
```

with

```
   this.variableA = "xyz";  // access variable as this.variableA
   this.setState({});
```

Is there any 'functional difference' in the above two code options?

I have a situation where maintaining state variables would create more problems than providing separation would compensate for.
 I have two components with shared 'states' i.e. changing something in component A changes rendering of component B and vice-versa - they both take inputs. Now if I were to maintain states, I will need callback functions both ways that can keep the shared state synchronised. It seems much easier to have the shared 'state' passed as an object reference in props and modify it on input and call setState({}) on both the components to re-render - we do not need to synchronise anymore. Is there any functional downside to this?

For e.g. consider -

```
class A extends React.component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => {
        this.props.data.reset(); 
        this.setState({});
      }}>
        <B data={this.props.data} onDataChange={() => {
          this.setState({});
        }}/>
        {/* ... */}
        {this.props.data.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class B extends React.component {
  render() {
     return (
       <input 
         type="text" 
         onChange={event => {
           this.props.data.value = event.target.value;
           this.props.onDataChange();
         }} 
         value={this.props.data.value} 
       />
     );
  }
}
```

I do not want to merge A and B as they both are significantly complex (the code above is just an example to show shared 'state').

Is there any functional issue in not capturing this.props.data in state variable?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). You've described a problem in your second paragraph, but your question is about something else (your attempted solution). It may be more productive to ask, instead, if what you're doing is the best way to solve your problem, rather than ask if there's any reason _not_ to do what you've done.

Comment: The answer to your question in the title is that using `state` triggers re-renders on state changes. Also react will be able to batch multiple updates to avoid unnecessary re-renders. Using simple instance variables does not allow react to observe state changes and to re-render accordingly. But your code example does not really reflect your question. Could you provide more details about what you are originally trying to achieve?

Comment: @trixn if I do call setState({}) after changing the variables, it takes care of re-rendering and multiple setState({}) calls would still be batched together. We can leave my code example for now (being discussed in LoremIpsum's answer) - it seems like I should have put two different questions here.

Comment: @JordanRunning yeah you're right, as I have put it, it is probably an XY problem, which I could have put as two different questions. Regardless, if someone can only answer the question - "Is there any 'functional difference' between using state variables and instance variables with setState({})?" I am editing my question title, while leaving the code there as someone is answering that too.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), i.e. move this shared state into their common ancestor and use props. That's basically what you're doing but without exposing the state outside of your components, which is not recommended.

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is like lifting the state up. So, are you recommending that instead of modifying props.data.<xyz> from the subcomponent, I do it via a callback? That would be too verbose and cumbersome if there are multiple such <xyz> variables. The other option would be to modify the variables from within the component and just signal a state change through a callback - I missed that callback in my code initially, added now (edited code). If I misunderstood you, could you clarify/elaborate please?

Comment: @adarsh Modifying props is an anti-pattern in react. The state should instead be lifted up to the parent which passes callbacks to the child to enable them to signalize something should change. The parent can then decide if changes to the state are required and possibly re-render the children with new props derived from the new state. Breaking the top-down data flow makes it very hard to reason about the behavior of the app. This principle makes react apps easy to understand and composable. So yes your should lift state up instead. Mutation is the source of all evil.

Comment: @trixn Props in react are shallow immutable anyway. If I were to write this.state.data = this.props.data in constructor and then modify this.state.data.<xyz> - would you still consider it modifying props? An anti-pattern should have a negative consequence and that is what I am trying to understand, instead of just following the said best-practices. If it helps to conceptualise, my class B would have been an 'inner class' in some other OOP languages.

Comment: @adarsh What is "shadow immutability"? Mutating props has a huge negative impact on the predictability of the behavior of your app and makes it very hard to reason about it and to debug it. Just because the language allows a certain practice does not mean it isn't an anti-pattern. And yes I would still consider that modifying props and this is still an anti-pattern. That's why you should use `setState()` which does not allow to mutate it this way. If you modify data you do not own (props) you basically introduce terrible side effects for your parent.

Comment: @trixn By 'shallow' immutability I meant that you can not modify direct attributes of props. I suppose you're thinking in terms of data-encapsulation and that attributes in props belong to the parent component, which in general would be correct, but if you think of the child component as 'belonging to the parent', you would not think of breaking encapsulation. You would not be using the child component without the parent in this case and vice-versa. That is why I asked to think it like an inner-class.

Comment: @trixn What you're suggesting is definitely doable, but for a complex component with tens of fields (prop attributes impacted by children callback) this would be way too verbose and cumbersome.

Comment: @adarsh I used react for quiet a long time now and also in big projects with hundreds of components and I never had any problem with components being to verbose or big. In fact most of our components are barely a single page long. There is always a way to abstract complexity in a way that keeps components small and clean and does not violate the top-down principle. Could you give an example of a use case where you think this is cumbersome? Do you speak about forms where you need a callback for  a lot of fields?

Comment: @trixn yes think of an 'object-editor'  (a form to edit an object) where the edited object renders a visual component, as the form is edited.